# Unable to create Jest testing module on NestJs service. Geting Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?, ConfigService)

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

it's my first time making questions on stackoverflow :).

So I'm developing a test / learning application to learn how to use NestJS and Vue.
I am was currently trying to implement several server-side unit tests (using Jest). When trying to create a testingmodule from my UsersService I get the error below on running "npm test users.service.spec"

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?,
>   ConfigService). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is
>   available in the _RootTestModule context.
>
> at Injector.lookupComponentInExports (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:183:19)

I am not sure if I am incorrectly instantiating the test model, or misconceived the injection of config.service, the code itself works, but may be implemented incorrectly.
Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem?

**Git link:** https://github.com/Lindul/FuelTracker_NestJs_MySql_Vue.git

**users.service.spec.ts**

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { UserDto } from './dto/user.dto';
import { UserLoginRegRequestDto } from './dto/user-login-reg-request.dto';
import { ConfigService } from '../shared/config/config.service';
describe('User Service Tests', () => {

    let loginTeste: UserLoginRegRequestDto = {
        login: 'LoginJestTeste',
        password: 'PassJestTeste',
    }

    const userMock: UserDto = {
        id: 1,
        login: 'hugombsantos',
        password: 'wefewkfnwekfnwekjnf',
        isActive: true,
        needChangePass: false,
        userType: 0,

    };

    const dataFindAllMock: UserDto[] = [{
        id: 1,
        login: 'hugombsantos',
        password: 'wefewkfnwekfnwekjnf',
        isActive: true,
        needChangePass: false,
        userType: 0,

    }, {
        id: 2,
        login: 'user2',
        password: 'sdgsdgdsgsdgsgsdg',
        isActive: true,
        needChangePass: false,
        userType: 0,
    }];

    let service: UsersService;
    beforeEach(async () => {

        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                ConfigService,
                UsersService,
            ],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
    });


    it('UsersService está defenido', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });   

});
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Users } from '../models/users.schema';
import { UserDto } from './dto/user.dto';
import { UserLoginRegRequestDto } from './dto/user-login-reg-request.dto';
import { UserLoginResponseDto } from './dto/user-login-response.dto';
import { sign } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { ConfigService } from '../shared/config/config.service';
import { JwtPayload } from './auth/jwt-payload.model';
import { ErroMessageDto } from '../shared/config/dto/erro-message.dto';
import { UpdateUserDto } from './dto/update-user.dto';
import bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const SALT_FACTOR = 8;

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

    constructor(
        @Inject('UsersRepository') private usersRepository: typeof Users,
        private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    ) { }

    /* istanbul ignore next */
    async findAll(): Promise<UserDto[]> {
        const users = await this.usersRepository.findAll<Users>();
        return users.map(user => {
            return new UserDto(user);
        });
    }
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    async findUser(id: number): Promise<Users> {
        const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne<Users>({
            where: { id },
        });
        return user;
    }
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    async findUserformLogin(login: string): Promise<UserDto> {
        return await this.usersRepository.findOne<Users>({
            where: { login },
        });
    }
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    async findUserforLogin(id: number, login: string): Promise<Users> {
        return await this.usersRepository.findOne<Users>({
            where: { id, login },
        });
    }
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    async creatUserOnDb(createUser: UserLoginRegRequestDto): Promise<Users> {
        try {
            const user = new Users();
            user.login = createUser.login;
            user.password = await this.hashPass(createUser.password);
            return await user.save();
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.original.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
                throw new HttpException(
                    new ErroMessageDto(
                        HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
                        `Login '${err.errors[0].value}' already exists`),
                    HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
                );
            }
            throw new HttpException(
                new ErroMessageDto(
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    err),
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            );
        }
    }
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    async updateUserOnDb(user: Users): Promise<Users> {
        try {
            return await user.save();
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.original.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
                throw new HttpException(
                    new ErroMessageDto(
                        HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
                        `Login '${err.errors[0].value}' already exists`),
                    HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
                );
            }
            throw new HttpException(
                new ErroMessageDto(
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    err),
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            );
        }
    }

    /* istanbul ignore next */
    async delete(id: number): Promise<UserDto> {
        const user = await this.findUser(+id);
        await user.destroy();
        return new UserDto(user);
    }

    async login(
        userLoginRequestDto: UserLoginRegRequestDto,
    ): Promise<UserLoginResponseDto> {

        const login = userLoginRequestDto.login;
        const password = userLoginRequestDto.password;
        const user = await this.findUserformLogin(login);

        if (!user) {
            throw new HttpException(
                new ErroMessageDto(
                    HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
                    'Invalid login or password.'),
                HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
            );
        }

        const isMatch = await this.comparePass(password, user.password);

        if (!isMatch) {
            throw new HttpException(
                new ErroMessageDto(
                    HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
                    'Invalid login or password.'),
                HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
            );
        }

        const token = await this.signToken(user);

        return new UserLoginResponseDto(token);
    }

    async create(createUser: UserLoginRegRequestDto): Promise<UserLoginResponseDto> {

        const userData = await this.creatUserOnDb(createUser);

        // when registering then log user in automatically by returning a token
        const token = await this.signToken(userData);

        return new UserLoginResponseDto(token);

    }

    async updateUser(id: number | string, updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto): Promise<UserLoginResponseDto> {

        const user = await this.findUser(+id);

        if (!user) {
            throw new HttpException(
                new ErroMessageDto(
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                    'User not found.'),
                HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
            );
        }

        user.login = updateUserDto.login || user.login;
        user.userType = updateUserDto.userType || user.userType;
        user.needChangePass = false;

        const isMatch = await this.comparePass(updateUserDto.password, user.password);
        if (updateUserDto.password && !isMatch) {
            user.password = await this.hashPass(updateUserDto.password);
        } else {
            user.password = user.password;
        }

        const userData = await this.updateUserOnDb(user);
        const token = await this.signToken(userData);

        return new UserLoginResponseDto(token);

    }

    async signToken(user: UserDto): Promise<string> {

        const payload: JwtPayload = {
            id: user.id,
            login: user.login,
        };
        const token = sign(payload, this.configService.jwtConfig.jwtPrivateKey,
            {
                expiresIn: this.configService.jwtConfig.valideTime,
            });
        return token;
    }

    async hashPass(passToHash: string): Promise<string> {
        const saltValue = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(SALT_FACTOR);
        return await bcrypt.hashSync(passToHash, saltValue);
    }

    async comparePass(passToCheck: string, correntPass: string) {
        return await bcrypt.compareSync(passToCheck, correntPass);
    }
}
```

**users.modules.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import {userProviders} from './users.providers';
import { DatabaseModule } from '../database/database.module';
import { JwtStrategy } from './auth/jwt-strategy';
import { ConfigService } from '../shared/config/config.service';

@Module({
  imports: [DatabaseModule, ConfigService],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService,
    ...userProviders, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [UsersService],

})

export class UsersModule {}
```

**config.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtConfig } from './interfaces/jwt-config.interface';
import { config } from '../../../config/config.JwT';
import { config as dbConfigData } from '../../../config/config.db';
import { SequelizeOrmConfig } from './interfaces/sequelize-orm-config.interface';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    get sequelizeOrmConfig(): SequelizeOrmConfig {
        return dbConfigData.databaseOpt;
    }

    get jwtConfig(): JwtConfig {
        return {
            jwtPrivateKey: config.jwtPrivateKey,
            valideTime: config.valideTime,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is "ConfigService" being imported as a module in "users.modules.ts" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some value for Nest to inject for your `UserRepository`. It looks like you are using the TypeORM `@InjectRepository()` decorator, so in your testing module you'll need to add something like this under your providers

```
{
  provide: getRepositoryToken('UsersRepository'),
  useValue: MyMockUserRepo,
}
```

So that Nest can know what value to inject for that string. `MyMockUserRepo` would be your mock repository functionality, so that you aren't making actual database calls to your backend

Comment: hello Jay. Thanks for the answer but the problem is that it is not usersRepository that is causing problems, it is ConfigService which I use to store system variables or constants.

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?, ConfigService).
And I had tried to muck but it still gives the same problem

Comment: Actually, the `?` in the error message is what Nest is having problems finding. You can check it against your `UserService` constructor to find out which value is giving it trouble. You can also check the rest of the error message where it says "Please make sure that the argument at index [0] " where index [0] is the first value of the constructor

Side note: you will probably want to use a mock of your configService as well instead of the actual class